# How to pause a slideshow on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to get the following slideshow to pause on mouse over. Right now when you hover over the image the slides bounce between 1 & 3 or 2 & 4 at what seems to be half of the timing.

```js
  var slideIndex = 1;
  var millis = 1000;

  nextSlide();
  var interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);

  function resumeSlides() {
    nextSlide();
  }

  function pauseSlides() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  function nextSlide() {
    showSlide();
    slideIndex++;
  }

  function plusSlides(n) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    slideIndex += n;
    nextSlide();
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    slideIndex = n + 1;
    nextSlide();
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);
  }

  function showSlide() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (slideIndex < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 600px;
}

.slideshow-nav {
  text-align:center; 
  padding: 30px 0;
}
  
.mySlides {
  width: auto;
}
  
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 6px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-2)">&#10094;</a>
  <div class="slideshow-nav">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(0)">&#10095;</a>

  <div onmouseover="pauseSlides()" onmouseout="resumeSlides()">
    <!--Slide 1-->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>Image 1</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/600">
    </div> 

    <!--Slide 2-->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>Image 2</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/600">
    </div>

    <!--Slide 3-->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>Image 3</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/600">
    </div>

    <!--Silde 4-->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>Image 4</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/600">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now that it's in the snippet I see there is an error.
"message": "ReferenceError: puaseSlides is not defined",
I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it.

Comment: `puaseSlides` is a misspelled `pauseSlides`

Comment: `<div onmouseover="pauseSlides()" onmouseout="resumeSlides()">`. Not ***"puaseSlides()"***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fix your typo `puaseSlides()`
2. Wrap your initialization code into a function (see `startSlides()`)
3. Use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
  var millis = 1000;
  var interval;
  
  startSlides();
  
  function startSlides(){
    pauseSlides();
    nextSlide();
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);
  }


  function resumeSlides() {
    nextSlide();
  }

  function pauseSlides() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  function nextSlide() {
    showSlide();
    slideIndex++;
  }

  function plusSlides(n) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    slideIndex += n;
    nextSlide();
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    slideIndex = n + 1;
    nextSlide();
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);
  }

  function showSlide() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (slideIndex < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 600px;
}

.slideshow-nav {
  text-align:center; 
  padding: 30px 0;
}
  
.mySlides {
  width: auto;
}
  
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 6px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-2)">&#10094;</a>
  <div class="slideshow-nav">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(0)">&#10095;</a>

  <div onmouseenter="pauseSlides()" onmouseleave="startSlides()">
    <!--Slide 1-->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>Image 1</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/600">
    </div> 

    <!--Slide 2-->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>Image 2</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/600">
    </div>

    <!--Slide 3-->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>Image 3</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/600">
    </div>

    <!--Silde 4-->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <p>Image 4</p>
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/600">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```